# AOE Scheduler - No heartbeat task found. Check if cron is configured correctly

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, schedule

We have Magento CE 1.9.0.1 where AOE Scheduler is configured for cron, and Magento cron is set to run on system after every 30 minutes as follows and shows no issues in /var/log/cron

> */30 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/cron.php

But, for some reason on back-end we always see error "No heartbeat task found. Check if cron is configured correctly." like follows and all status grayed and are always set to 'PENDING'

[image]

Following are the settings for System > Schedular > Job Configuration

[image]

And following are the settings for System > Cron Configuration

[image]

If we run the cron manually via command line or via browser than "No heartbeat task found..." issue goes for some minutes but again comes in, also if settings Magento cron to run every 5 minutes it goes away! but that overlaps other running tasks so we have to run it every 30 minutes at least.

What could be the issue here with 30 minutes interval which always shows "No heartbeat task found..." and all tasks pending to grayed with PENDING status?

Comment: Can you check date/time on server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in System > Schedular > Job Configuration aoescheduler_heartbeat is set to run every 5 minutes. When this task isn't run it reports that it has not been run.

Rather than setting the cron to run every 30 minutes why not set it to run every 5 minutes and adjust the frequency of the tasks that are overlapping?

You didn't state which tasks are overlapping but for example if it was xml_notification_send_all, you could change it's execution from */5 * * * * to */30 * * * * to have just that task run every 30 minutes rather than every task.